# Accord du participe passé avec COD

Tags: grammaire

Est-ce qu'on doit faire l'accord dans la phrase suivante? Pourquoi? / Pourquoi pas?

- Allô, c'est Alice, tu m'as **appelé(e)**?

Answer (score 2):

Oui, l'accord doit se faire parce que le COD (*m'*, contradiction de "me") est placé **avant** le verbe.

Une méthode simple pour trancher est de poser la question :

> Tu as appelé **qui** ?

Si tu peux dire "qui" ou "quoi" et **non** "à qui", "de qui", "à quoi" ou "de quoi", alors tu as un COD. À contrario :

> Il lui a parlé

ne s'accorde jamais, parce que "lui" est un COI et non un COD. En effet, tu peux dire :

> Il a parlé **à qui** ?